# Windows, GTK+, gtk_file_chooser_get_filename() и fopen()

Tags: c, gtk, fopen

В общем, проблема следующая.

Насколько я понимаю:

1) При использовании стандартного **GTK+** диалога выбора файла и последующего вызова:

```
char *file_name = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(...);
```

Я получаю строку с путем и именем файла в виде строки **utf-8**?

2) Стандартный **fopen()** просит строку однобайтовых символов в системной кодировке?

Проблема в том, что если в пути/имени файла, который я открываю при помощи стандартного диалога **GTK+**, имеются кириллические символы или символы, не входящие в первую (статичную) половину таблицы **ANSI**, то нельзя так просто взять строку, полученную из **gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()**, и передать в **fopen()**, потому что *not true* символы будут представлены несколькими байтами, согласно правилам кодировки **utf-8**.

Подскажите, какие есть варианты перевода символов из **utf-8** в то, что **fopen()** сможет корректно обработать?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) При использовании стандартного GTK+ диалога выбора файла и последующего вызова:
>   Я получаю строку с путем и именем файла в виде строки utf-8?

[Не обязательно](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#id-1.3.14.6.11.5), по умолчанию это utf-8, но может быть любая другая заданная в `G_FILENAME_ENCODING`.

> Стандартный fopen() просит строку однобайтовых символов в системной кодировке?

Да, на абсолютном большинстве современных *nix систем кодировка ФС совпадает с системной локалью и является utf-8. Что на прочих системах — сказать не могу.

> Подскажите, какие есть варианты перевода символов из utf-8 в то, что fopen() сможет корректно обработать?

Строка полученная от `gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()` напрямую [предначначена](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion#id-1.5.3.6.5) для передачи в `fopen ()` и пр. Ни каких дополнителных действий не требуется.

**Upd.**

AFAIK открытие файла с не-ASCII именем на windows через `fopen ()` — вообще говоря, [нетривиальная задача](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx). GTK/GLib для переносимости на не-очень-POSIX системы предлогают использовать GLib'ные обёртки, в частности [`g_fopen()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.56/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-fopen). Оные доподлинно принимают аргумент в той же кодировке, что возвращает gtk_file_chooser_get_filename () и др.

Comment: При передаче строки напрямую из **gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()** в **fopen()** - файл открыть не удается, если в его имени есть кириллические символы.

Comment: @Максим, УМВР: [код](http://paste.debian.net/1037761/), [вывод](http://paste.debian.net/1037762/).... ОС? кодировка фс?

Comment: Windows 10, NTFS, кодировкой фс не интересовался...

Comment: @Максим, м... как и говорил. что на не-*nix системах я не особо знаю, но дополнил ответ после поверхностного гуглежа... ЗЫ: на будущее, в подобных вопросах лучше сразу указывать, что дело происходит на какой-то необычной системе...